# assembly language code doesn't add correctly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to write an assembly language code that multiples a number by 2(without using multiplication) and print it out, but my assembly code is not working- it is printing 0 when it should be printing 20. I checked and I did initialize the %r10 to 10, but then after I copied %r10 to %r11 value of %r10 just becomes an unrelated number (582). Can someone help point out what I am doing wrong and how should I implement it? Thank you!

```
    .section .rodata
sOutputFmt: .string "%ld\n"
    .section .text
    .globl main
main:
    subq $8,%rsp
    movq $10,%r10
    
    movq %r11,%r10
    
    addq %r11,%r10
    addq %r11,%r10

    movq $sOutputFmt,%rdi
    movq %r10,%rsi
    call printf
    
    addq $8,%rsp
    ret
```

Comment: Ok, so you know what instruction is wrong. I suggest you check `r10` and `r11` (or maybe all the registers) both before that instruction and then again immediately after it, to see what happened and how to fix.

Comment: um I think the problem is %r11, I changed it to %r13, and all of a sudden this code performs correctly. But I am still very confused about why this is the case...

Comment: oh, I think I figured out what I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, seems you mixed Intel and AT&T syntax.

Comment: The subject line is an indicator of a way to adust your thought processes. The assembly language code adds correctly. It's understanding of what the code is doing that's in short supply, as you discovered. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
movq $10,  %r10
movq %r11, %r10
```

AT&T syntax (as opposed to Intel syntax) has the source first *then* the destination. So the first line above correctly loads `10` into `r10`, then the second loads whatever was in `r11` (probably zero based on your results) into `r10`, overwriting it.

If you want `r11` to end up double `r10`, the sequence would be something like:

```
movq %r10, %r11  ; r11 <- r10
addq %r10, %r11  ; r11 <- r11 + r10
```

Notice there's a `mov` and a *single* `add` there. Your original code has a `mov` followed by two `add` instructions, meaning you would end up multiplying by *three* rather than two.